# Функция возврата половины

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Получил такое вот задание - сделать шаблонную функцию которая сможет принять `int float string` и вернет от чисел и строки половину. 
Идей вообще нет.. Вот набросок который компилирует но выдает ошибку при вызове..

```
template <typename Type>
Type max(Type a) {
    if (typeid(a).name()[0]=='A'){ // тип строка
    if (strlen(a)>1) { //больше одной буквы
        a[strlen(a)/2]='\0';} // режем пополам
    return a; //возвр строку
 }else{
    return a/2;//вовр число
 } 
}
```

к примеру что должно быть в итоге
Вызовы:

```
      int a = max(10); // 5
      float b = max(5.8); //2.9
      string c =max("Hashcode") //Hash
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, или дайте идею или пример как сделать)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё просто: http://ideone.com/VJ4LH1

Это называется «явная специализация шаблона».

```
template<typename T>
T half(T arg);

template<>
int half<int>(int arg)
{
    return arg/2;
}

template<>
double half<double>(double arg)
{
    return arg/2;
}

template<>
string half<string>(string arg)
{
    return arg.substr(0, arg.length()/2);
}
```

Для более продвинутых случаев, почитайте про [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, с помощью SFINAE необходимо сделать следующий шаблон (подходит под условие задачи):

1. проверить определен ли оператор `/` для типа, если да - задействовать его. При этом определять специализации шаблона для целочисленных и вещественных чисел становится ненужно.
2. если нет - проверить является ли тип контейнером (string, vector, list и пр.). Если да - вернуть первую половину контейнера.
3. в остальных случаях вернуть ошибку.

Comment: @gecube: со SFINAE как-то так: http://ideone.com/DuBaF5

Или проще, с `boost::enable_if`/`boost::is_arithmetic`.

Answer (score -1):

Тот, кто вам это задал вообще понимает что такое шаблоны и зачем они?

Вообще шаблонные функции делаются когда тип данных меняется а алгоритм один и тот же, а в случае с

1. `int,float`... вам нужно разделить
       переменную на 2 и вернуть результат
2. `string` найти середину, создать новую
       строку скопировать туда
       половину(кстати какую именно
       половину?) и вернуть результат
3. а что делать в случае с объектами?
4. что делать в случае коллекций?

как видите, везде алгоритм разный...

---

---

---

можно конечно извратиться и сделать явное предопределение шаблона на определённый тип (забыл точное название таких шаблонов)

или ещё больший изврат с определением типа внутри шаблона

Comment: > можно конечно извратиться и сделать явное предопределение шаблона на определённый тип (забыл точное название таких шаблонов)

Специализация шаблона???

Comment: ага, она самая!